# Testing a Collatz Conjecture Conjecture (Python)

Tags: python, beginner, collatz-sequence

I had an intuition that the maximal trajectory lengths for collatz conjecture numbers would be produced by numbers of the form `(2**n)-1` so I wrote a program to test it (I was wrong). I thought I would put it up for review to catch any coding sins I committed, and see how others would improve my code.

#### Orginal Code

```
'''
*    I had a conjecture that maximal trajectory lengths for the collatz conjecture were yielded by numbers of the form (2**n)-1. This program attempts to test it.
*    "conjecture()" finds the number with the highest trajectory lengths in a given range. The ranges are of the form [2**n, 2**(n+1)).
'''

import math, pprint

f = open("CollatzConjecture.txt")
text =  f.read()

def key(value, dct):
    for key in dct.keys():
        if dct[key] == value:
            return key
    return None


def conjecture(text):
    traj = {int(j.split(" ")[0]): int(j.split(" ")[1]) for j in text.split("\n")}    #Processes the text file into a dict mapping numbers to their trajectory length.
    result = {}
    bound = math.floor(math.log(len(traj),2))
    traj2 = {num: traj[num] for num in list(traj.keys())[:2**bound+1]}    #Slices the dictionary to receive the section of interest.
    for st in (2**x for x in range(1, bound+1)):        #Generator for powers of 2.
        slce = list(traj2.items())[int((math.log(st,2)-1)**2):st]    #Slices "traj2" into powers of 2.
        result[st] = key(max([n[1] for n in slce]), traj2)
    return pprint.pformat(result)

print(conjecture(text))
```

["CollatzConjecture.txt"](https://oeis.org/A006577/b006577.txt) is a text file containing `number trajectoryLength` on separate lines. I wanted to find the number corresponding to the maximum trajectory length between successive powers of 2 in order to test my hypothesis.

Comment: Can you add an example input textfile?

Comment: Where is the `key` function actually used?

Comment: @Ludisposed I'll link the actual text file I used: https://oeis.org/A006577/b006577.txt

Comment: @Graipher key is no longer been used in the current version. I used it in an older version. I'll edit it to remove it.

Comment: Please do not update the code in your question to incorporate feedback from answers, doing so goes against the Question + Answer style of Code Review. This is not a forum where you should keep the most updated version in your question. Please see *[what you may and may not do after receiving answers](//codereview.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1765)*. The existing answer explicitly mentions a piece of code you tried to remove, so your edit would invalidate it. We can't have that.

Comment: @Mast Aah. I would replace the code with the code I used initially:

Comment: @TobiAlafin: I rolled it back to your first revision and added the link to OEIS manually. I hope that did not screw it up further but is now actually your original code, to which the answer by Ludisposed belongs.

Comment: Now that you have improved code it might make sense to ask a new question with the updated code, linking back to this one, as stated in the link provided by Mast.

Comment: @Graipher I overwrote your edit. I'll roll back the addition of the edited version.

Comment: @TobiAlafin: Hm, what a nice edit mess :) I'll let you figure it out, but if I were you, I would just roll it back to your first first revision (again) and then forget about this question. Instead spend the effort on making the follow-up question look good.

Answer (score 10):

> ```
> def key(value, dct):
>     for key in dct.keys():
>         if dct[key] == value:
>             return key
>     return None
> ```

This is really inefficient and not how dictionaries should be used.

- The point of a `dict` is O(1) lookup, this is essentially O(n) and it doesn't make sense
- You should remove your blockcomments, and create a nice docstring. That will make the purpose of the code clearer
- You don't close the file, a nice addition is using the `with` statement to automatically open/close files [PEP343](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/)

Comment: `key(value, dct)` gets the key corresponding to a value. `dict.get()` gets the value corresponding to a key. I'll edit my code to make it clearer.

Comment: @TobiAlafin: If you need to map both ways (A -> B and B -> A), *use two dictionaries to get O(1) lookups in each direction*.  A linear search O(n) in one direction vs. an O(1) in the other, doesn't make sense, unless that direction is almost never used, and you can't afford to double the storage cost by keeping a reverse dictionary.  Or there are probably custom data structures that can index on both sets of data without duplicating the storage... like what a relational database would use for a table with 2 columns, and an index on each column.  For short keys two dicts is totally fine.

Comment: Peter Cordes thank you. I had not thought of that, I'll apply that in the future.

Answer (score 4):

First of all, thumbs up on including a documentation block at the beginning.

When trying to run the segment, I get

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "conjecture.py", line 28, in <module>
    print(conjecture(text))
  File "conjecture.py", line 19, in conjecture
    traj = {int(j.split(" ")[0]): int(j.split(" ")[1]) for j in text.split("\n")}    #Processes the text file into a dict mapping numbers to their trajectory length.
  File "conjecture.py", line 19, in <dictcomp>
    traj = {int(j.split(" ")[0]): int(j.split(" ")[1]) for j in text.split("\n")}    #Processes the text file into a dict mapping numbers to their trajectory length.
IndexError: list index out of range
```

Turns out that when I saved the output of the link, there were empty trailing lines. After fixing that, I could get it to run.

Furthermore, I see several issues with this implementation:

1. The `conjecture` function is doing a lot of the work, with several lines that are quite filled with operations, meaning it's hard to find out what it's doing.
2. A dictionary can contain a value multiple times, and in fact does. For instance, both 5 and 32 have a length of 5 (5 -> 16 -> ...) and (32 -> 16 -> ...). For longer lengths, there will be more ways in which it can be obtained.
3. Floating point arithmetic in a fully integral problem seems like an issue.
4. The file is opened, and then not immediately closed. For this it's not really an issue, but in general one should use a contextmanager to clean up used resources as quickly as possible.
5. The semantics of the output isn't really clear to me, but I'll probably figure out a bit during picking it apart.
6. It doesn't use a `__main__` block, which would be beneficial for re-usable code.
7. The `conjecture` function returns a string, instead of a dictionary.

So let's start with your implementation:

```
'''
*    I had a conjecture that maximal trajectory lengths for the collatz conjecture were yielded by numbers of the form (2**n)-1. This program attempts to test it.
*    "conjecture()" finds the number with the highest trajectory lengths in a given range. The ranges are of the form [2**n, 2**(n+1)).
'''

import math, pprint

f = open("CollatzConjecture.txt")
text =  f.read()

def key(value, dct):
    for key in dct.keys():
        if dct[key] == value:
            return key
    return None


def conjecture(text):
    traj = {int(j.split(" ")[0]): int(j.split(" ")[1]) for j in text.split("\n")}    #Processes the text file into a dict mapping numbers to their trajectory length.
    result = {}
    bound = math.floor(math.log(len(traj),2))
    traj2 = {num: traj[num] for num in list(traj.keys())[:2**bound+1]}    #Slices the dictionary to receive the section of interest.
    for st in (2**x for x in range(1, bound+1)):        #Generator for powers of 2.
        slce = list(traj2.items())[int((math.log(st,2)-1)**2):st]    #Slices "traj2" into powers of 2.
        result[st] = key(max([n[1] for n in slce]), traj2)
    return pprint.pformat(result)

print(conjecture(text))
```

## Use a `if __name__ == '__main__'` segment.

One of the best places to start with such a script (especially if you want to make it reusable!) is to place the "main" code (file-mangling) inside a `main` block:

```
... function definitions ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open("CollatzConjecture.txt")
    text = f.read()
    print(conjecture(text))
```

## Move parsing the trajectories out of `conjecture`.

Your conjecture has nothing to do with the piece of text, but about the length of the trajectories. We shouldn't care how these lengths are generated, calculated or parsed inside the `conjecture` function. But the current implementation does.

By moving out the `text` to `traj` transformation, we make `conjecture` more general.

```
...

def conjecture(traj):
    result = {}
    bound = math.floor(math.log(len(traj),2))
    ...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    f = open("CollatzConjecture.txt")
    text = f.read()
    traj = {int(j.split(" ")[0]): int(j.split(" ")[1]) for j in text.split("\n")}    #Processes the text file into a dict mapping numbers to their trajectory length.
    print(conjecture(traj))
```

And we can then split the parsing into a separate function, where we use a context manager.

```
...

def parse_lengths(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        #Processes the text file into a dict mapping numbers to their trajectory length.
        return {int(j.split(" ")[0]): int(j.split(" ")[1]) for j in fp}

...

if __name__ == '__main__':
    traj = parse_lengths("CollatzConjecture.txt")
    print(conjecture(traj))
```

And similarly, move the pformat out of conjecture:

```
def conjecture(text):
    result = {}
    ...
    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    traj = parse_lengths("CollatzConjecture.txt")
    pprint.pprint(conjecture(traj))
```

## Simplify `conjecture`.

Now that we're left with a `conjecture` method that does only things related to the conjecture, we can look at it a bit more:

```
def conjecture(traj):
    result = {}
    bound = math.floor(math.log(len(traj),2))
    traj2 = {num: traj[num] for num in list(traj.keys())[:2**bound+1]}    #Slices the dictionary to receive the section of interest.
    for st in (2**x for x in range(1, bound+1)):        #Generator for powers of 2.
        slce = list(traj2.items())[int((math.log(st,2)-1)**2):st]    #Slices "traj2" into powers of 2.
        result[st] = key(max([n[1] for n in slce]), traj2)
    return result
```

Starting with this expression: `int((math.log(st,2)-1)**2)`, what does it even do?! First it takes the 2-logarithm, substracts 1, and then squares it. At first I suspected that you wanted the previous power of two (and tested it). But, what actually happens is that 64 (2<sup>6</sup>) becomes 25 (5<sup>2</sup>), and also 2048 (2<sup>11</sup>) becomes 100 (10<sup>2</sup>). My basic guess is that this is incorrect, and you mean 64 => 32, 128 => 64, and so forth. Assuming that's what you want, you can just divide by two.

```
def conjecture(traj):
    result = {}
    bound = math.floor(math.log(len(traj),2))
    traj2 = {num: traj[num] for num in list(traj.keys())[:2**bound+1]}    #Slices the dictionary to receive the section of interest.
    for st in (2**x for x in range(1, bound+1)):        #Generator for powers of 2.
        slce = list(traj2.items())[st // 2:st]    #Slices "traj2" into powers of 2.
        result[st] = key(max([n[1] for n in slce]), traj2)
    return result
```

Surprisingly, though, this does not alter the output.

Next up is the fact that I see slices being taken of dictionaries (after casting to a list). In older Python versions (before 3.6) that might cause surprising results, as dictionaries are not necessarily ordered by value, though in this case it does turn out to be that way it seems. It's better to explicitly filter out the values that you want.

## Final:

In the end, I found myself settling on this.

```
'''
*    I had a conjecture that maximal trajectory lengths for the collatz conjecture were yielded by numbers of the form (2**n)-1. This program attempts to test it.
*    "conjecture()" finds the number with the highest trajectory lengths in a given range. The ranges are of the form [2**n, 2**(n+1)).
'''

import pprint

def key(value, dct):
    for key in dct.keys():
        if dct[key] == value:
            return key
    return None


def parse_lengths(filename):
    with open(filename) as fp:
        #Processes the text file into a dict mapping numbers to their trajectory length.
        return {int(j.split(" ")[0]): int(j.split(" ")[1]) for j in fp}


def conjecture(traj):
    result = {}
    traj_size = len(traj)
    lower, higher = 1, 2
    while True:
        if higher > traj_size:
            # We don't have all the data for this range available.
            break

        max_in_slice = max(length for num, length in traj.items() if lower <= num <= higher)

        result[higher] = key(max_in_slice, traj)

        # Prepare data for next iteration.
        lower, higher = lower * 2, higher * 2

    return result

if __name__ == '__main__':
    traj = parse_lengths('CollatzConjecture.txt')
    pprint.pprint(conjecture(traj))
```

I'm also not quite happy with this yet, as the "key" function is still bothering me as well (we could iterate over `.items()` instead of `.keys()` to simplify).

I hope this at least helps a bit.

Answer (score 3):

It's desirable to try to break one's code into small, more reusable segments. For example, it would be preferable (in my opinion) to create a small function to open the text file, extract its contents, and return the `dict` of trajectories you desire:

```
def load_trajectories(file_name):
    traj = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            S = line.split(' ')
            num, traj_len = int(S[0]), int(S[1])
            traj[num] = traj_len
    return traj
```

Note here that I used the context manager `with open(file_name, 'r') as f:`, since in Python we need to first open a file, do things with it, and then close it. The context manager handles the opening and closing of the file for us, and within it we can access the file.

From my searching there doesn't seem to be a universally accepted way to find the "inverse" of a value in a dictionary, but I like yours for the most part. As one change, I would iterate over the `key:value` pairs to simplify things a bit:

```
def find_key(target_value, dct):
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if val == target_value:
            return key
    raise Exception('Value not found!')
```

With this, it really only remains to clean up the `conjecture` function. Here, we can pass the `traj` dictionary as an argument, as well as the (un-exponentiated) bound.

In the parlance of your code, note that `st` is always of the form `2**x`, so when we compute `math.log(st, 2)`, it always evaluates to `x`, so one line of your code reads (equivalently)

```
slce = list(traj2.items())[(x-1)**2:st]
```

which isn't the 'slicing into power of 2' that you desire. Moreover, it's not (necessarily) guaranteed that `traj2.items()` will be turned into a list in the way you desire, so it'll be better to be more explicit:

```
slce = [key, val for key, val in traj.items() if key in range(2**(x-1), 2**x)]
```

Together, along with splitting our imports onto different lines, [adding a `if __name__ == '__main__':`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/419163/what-does-if-name-main-do) guard, and some other minor reorganization yields the following code:

```
import math
import pprint

def find_key(target_value, dct):
    for key, val in dct.items():
        if val == target_value:
            return key
    raise Exception('Value not found!')

def load_trajectories(file_name):
    traj = {}
    with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.readlines():
            S = line.split(' ')
            num, traj_len = int(S[0]), int(S[1])
            traj[num] = traj_len
    return traj

def conjecture(traj):
    """Checks the conjecture that the maximum 'Collatz length' among the integers in [2**n, 2**(n+1)) is 2**n - 1.

    The conjecture is false.
    """
    bound = math.floor(math.log(len(traj),2))
    exp_bound = 2**bound

    traj = {key:val for key, val in traj.items() if key < exp_bound} # Only include numbers of interest.
    result = {}

    for n in range(1,bound+1):
        exp_n = 2**n
        slce = [key, val for key, val in traj.items() if key in range(2**(n-1), exp_n)]
        result[exp_n] = find_key(max([val for key, val in slce]), traj)

    return pprint(pformat(result))

if __name__ == "__main__":

    file_name = "CollatzConjecture.txt"
    print(conjecture(file_name))
```

Comment: "*I would iterate over the `key:value` pairs to simplify things a bit*": it's not just a question of simplifying. It's also more efficient, because advancing the iterator doesn't involve any search so is as cheap as possible, whereas the lookup potentially has to resolve hash collisions.

Answer (score 1):

The existing answers cover most of the issues that I spotted. There's just one thing that I think it's useful to add:

> ```
>     for st in (2**x for x in range(1, bound+1)):        #Generator for powers of 2.
>         slce = list(traj2.items())[int((math.log(st,2)-1)**2):st]    #Slices "traj2" into powers of 2.
>         result[st] = key(max([n[1] for n in slce]), traj2)
> ```

This converts the `dict` into a list every time through the loop. The suggestions, which don't rely on undocumented behaviour, instead filter the `dict` each time through the loop. But you can instead invert the loop:

```
    best = [0] * (bound + 1)
    for key, value in traj2.items():
        x = int(math.log(key, 2)) + 1
        if value > best[x] or (value == best[x] and key < result[2**x]):
            best[x] = value
            result[2**x] = key
```

This gives straightforward linear running time and allows you explicit control over tie-breaking. (I'm not sure whether I've got the tie-breaking correct for your conjecture, but you can easily fix that).